# Cannot seem to reload store in EXTjs 3.4 after adding parameter to proxy url

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a store retrieved from a url.  The url takes parameters to return the correct array of values to populate a dropdown (select). I initialize the dropdown from the complete list and after user interaction I am trying to update the store and dropdown with new object values.  I can get the proxy url and update it, I can get the store and clear it.  But whenever I load() or reload() the original list (as if the proxy is the same as init) comes into the dropdown not the filtered one.
Another curious thing is that the methods getProxy() and refresh() do not seem to be available.  I am using EXTjs 3.4
this is how I create the store:

```
Ext.namespace('Ext.emailData');
    Ext.emailData.storedEmails = new Ext.data.Store({
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            fields: ['email','id'],
            root: 'result'
        }),
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: '/emailContact/list',
            method: 'POST'
        }),
        sortInfo: {field: 'email', direction: 'ASC'}
    });
//
// now this is how I try to update it after associating it with the selectbox
//
var myfield = Ext.getCmp('my_form').getForm().findField('recipient_input');
myfield.clearValue();
myfield.getStore().proxy.url = '/emailContact/list' + getListById();
myfield.getStore().reload();
//
// and this is how I add the store to the select
//
store: Ext.emailData.storedEmails,
```

Comment: setURL is in the docs on the HttpProxy - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.HttpProxy-method-setUrl. Definitely don't use reload since this will use the last set of params used on the last load operation, so your original request in your example code. What does getListById() return just out of interest?

Comment: the paramer needed for the java page ie: ?email=all20%emails

Comment: THANK YOU!  I had tried : .getStore().getProxy().setUrl() not .getStore().proxy.setUrl() and the latter worked! Thanks for the suggestion to make me look back at it!  please post as an answer and I will accept it.